# How to remove a property from a Delphi DFM file?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got a lot of files (DFM Delphi source files) in which I would like to remove a specific property from all components of a specific class.

Each component definition starts with the word `object` or `inherited`, followed by:

- Empty space
- The name of the component (alphanumeric)
- Colon `:`
- Empty space
- The class of the component (alphanumeric)

Following lines represents properties of the component and are composed by:

- Property name (alphanumeric)
- Empty space
- Equals sign `=`
- Empty space
- Property value (alphanumeric)

There also could be other nested components, following the same syntax rules.

The component definition finishes with the `end` keyword.
Here is an example:

```
inherited Test: TTest
  OtherProperty = 'Hello'
  inherited Component1: TTargetClass
    OtherProperty = 100
    TargetProperty = True
  end
  object Component1: TTargetClass
    OtherProperty = 'Hello'
  end
  object Component2: TPanel
    OtherProperty = 100
    TargetProperty = True
    object NestedComponent1: TTargetClass
      OtherProperty = 'Hello'
      TargetProperty = False
    end
  end
end
```

Probably it's not the best way for doing this but I want to accomplish my goal by using a `RegEx` in `Notepad++`.
The property I want to remove is `TargetProperty` and I want to remove the lines who contains it only from components of class `TTargetClass`.

```
inherited Test: TTest
  OtherProperty = 'Hello'
  inherited Component1: TTargetClass
    OtherProperty = 100
  end
  object Component1: TTargetClass
    OtherProperty = 'Hello'
  end
  object Component2: TPanel
    OtherProperty = 100
    TargetProperty = True
    object NestedComponent1: TTargetClass
      OtherProperty = 'Hello'
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried the following `RegEx` but it matches from the first `TTargetClass` to the last `end`:

```
TTargetClass.*(TargetProperty.*\R)end
```

Comment: Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/xl7sLo/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It causes a little indentation's problem but it works also on notepad++

Comment: I wrote the pattern inside Notepad++, that is why it is working there :) As for indentation, it can only be "fixed" if you always have the same indentation in the matches. Is the indentation the same? Is it 2 tabs or 8 spaces?

Comment: Ah, check [this one](https://regex101.com/r/xl7sLo/3). It seems to preserve the indentation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes! thank you, post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(TTargetClass(?:\R(?!\h*end$).*)*?)^\h*TargetProperty.*\R+(\h*end$)
```

and replace with `$1$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xl7sLo/4/).

[image]

**Details**

- `(TTargetClass(?:\R(?!\h*end$).*)*?)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `TTargetClass` - a literal substring
  - `(?:\R(?!\h*end$).*)*?` - zero or more, but as few as possible, seuqences of:

    - `\R(?!\h*end$)` - a line break that is not followed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces (`\h*`) and then an `end` substring at the end of the line (`$`)
    - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `^\h*` - start of a line with 0+ horizontal whitespaces after
- `TargetProperty` - a literal substring
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\R+` - 1 or more line breaks
- `(\h*end$)` - Group 2: 0+ horizontal whitespaces and `end` substring at the end of the line.

The `$1` is a backreference that refers to the text captured with Group 1 and `$2` refers to the text captured with Group 2.